# Can we extend the group action from subgroups?

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

Let $G$ be a group and $H,K$ be subgroups of $G$ such that $G=<H,K>$. Suppose that $H,K$ acts on the set $S$.

Is there any condition that which guarantees that action of $H,K$ is extended to action of $G$ ?

What I mean can we define action of $G$ by the actions of $H,K$ ? Probably we need some compability conditions. What are they ?

Comment: The compatibility conditions are whatever relations are satisfied between the elements of $H$ and the elements of $K$ in $G$. If $G$ is their free product then there are no such conditions.

Comment: I think the necassry one is that $H\cap K$  acts same as a subgroup of $H$ and as a subgroup of $K$.

Comment: That's necessary, but it's not sufficient. Think of $H = \mathbb{Z} \times 0, K = 0 \times \mathbb{Z}$ as subgroups of $G = \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$, and consider actions of $H$ and $K$ whose generators don't commute.